# EF core - parent.InverseParent returns null for some rows

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a Category table and it has a Parent Category, I try to iterate over all the categories and get the parents categories with it's Inverse Parent but some of them returns without the inverse parents from unknown reason.

Categories.cs

```
 public partial class Categories
{
    public Categories()
    {
        InverseParent = new HashSet<Categories>();   
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public bool? Status { get; set; }

    public virtual Categories Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Categories> InverseParent { get; set; }

}
```

This is how I try to iterate them to create a select list items:

```
  var parentCategories = await _context.Categories.
                                                      Include(x => x.Parent).
                                                      Where(x => x.Status == true).
                                                      Where(x => x.Parent != null).
                                                      Select(x => x.Parent).
                                                      Distinct().
                                                      ToListAsync();

                foreach (var parent in parentCategories)
                {
                    SelectListGroup group = new SelectListGroup() { Name = parent.Id.ToString() };
                    foreach (var category in parent.InverseParent)
                    {
                        categories.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = category.Id.ToString(), Value = category.Id.ToString(), Group = group });
                    }
                }
```

So the problem is that some of my parent categories returns all their children categories and some don't and I don't why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with that code, all having some explaination in the [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) section of the documentation.

First, you didn't ask EF Core to include `InverseParent`, so it's more logically to expect it to be *always* `null`.

What you get is a result of the following [Eager Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading) behavior:

> **Tip**
>
> Entity Framework Core will automatically fix-up navigation properties to any other entities that were previously loaded into the context instance. So even if you don't explicitly include the data for a navigation property, the property may still be populated if some or all of the related entities were previously loaded.

Second, since the query is changing it's initial shape (`Select`, `Disctinct`), it's falling into [Ignored Includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes) category.

With that being said, you should build the query other way around - starting directly with parent categories and including `InverseParent`:

```
var parentCategories = await _context.Categories
    .Include(x => x.InverseParent)
    .Where(x => x.InverseParent.Any(c => c.Status == true)) // to match your query filter
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This way seems better than group by

Comment: Ivan, can you solve this other question of mine also? same issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56004174/ef-core-inverseparent-inconsistency-behavior

Comment: @OffirPe'er Yeah, same issue and same cause - may be you've missed the main point here - once you do `Select`, `Distinct` etc, `Include`s do not work.

Comment: Ok, I understand that when I use `Select` or `Distinct` in the same query it drops that include part. 
But why it works when the first variable existing?

Comment: @OffirPe'er That's the side effect of change tracking and navigation property fixup as explained in the aforementioned **Tip** - note the last paragraph *" the property **may still be populated** if some or all of the related entities were previously loaded"*. By executing first `ToList` some data is loaded and tracked inside context.

Answer (score 0):

While you are including `Include(x => x.Parent)`, you don't seem to do the same for `InverseParent`. This might affect your results exactly the way you describe. Would including it fix it?

```
parentCategories = await _context.Categories.
                                                      Include(x => x.Parent).
                                                      Include(x => x.InverseParent).
                                                      Where(x => x.Status == true).
                                                      Where(x => x.Parent != null).
                                                      Select(x => x.Parent).
                                                      Distinct().
                                                      ToListAsync();

                foreach (var parent in parentCategories)
                {
                    SelectListGroup group = new SelectListGroup() { Name = parent.Id.ToString() };
                    foreach (var category in parent.InverseParent)
                    {
                        categories.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = category.Id.ToString(), Value = category.Id.ToString(), Group = group });
                    }
                }
```

UPD: Since you are selecting `x => x.Parent` anyway it might be necessary to use `ThenInclude()` method instead.

Comment: I tried both solutions you offer, it still partially works, let's say I have parent category with 4 children categories, only 2 returns as InverseParent.

Comment: *"Would including it fix it?"* I'm confused - isn't this supposed to be an answer rather than a question?